# Max value per group based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with following columns which stores fileNumber and version.

```
id, fileNumber, version, approved (0/1) .
```

There can be multiple versions of the same fileNumber. If a specific fileNumber and version is approved, approved column value will be 1.

I need to write an efficient query to find out the max(version) given a fileNumber.

The rules (in order of precedence) are:

1) if there is an approved version, get the max(version) where approved=1

2) if there is no approved version, simply get max(version)

Database is oracle.

Comment: Union with where clauses dependent on [approved] column?

Comment: there can be multiple approved versions for the same FileNumber. Need to apply the rules listed in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select filenumber,
       coalesce(max(case when approved = 1 then version end),
                max(version)
               ) as your_max_version
from t
group by filenumber;
```

In Oracle, you can also do this using `keep`:

```
select filenumber,
       max(version) keep (dense_rank first order by approved desc, version desc) as your_max_version
from t
group by filenumber;
```

I would speculate that the first version would be a little bit faster, but I am usually impressed by the performance of `keep`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably simplest to solve by ordering and selecting the top row:

```
 select * from(
  SELECT
   *
  FROM
   table
  WHERE 
   filenumber = x
  ORDER BY
   approved DESC, version DESC
 ) a
 WHERE rownum = 1
```

Later versions of oracle (12c+) don't need a subquery:

```
  SELECT
   *
  FROM
   table
  WHERE 
   filenumber = x
  ORDER BY
   approved DESC, version DESC
  OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Does it return version number _for each fileNumber_?

Comment: You didn't ask for a version number for each file number, you said "I need to write an efficient query to find out the max(version) given a fileNumber" - by "given a file number" I understood you to mean you already have exactly one file number and are seeking its max version according to the rules as stated

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT fileNumber,
       COALESCE(max_approved, max_overall)
FROM (
    SELECT fileNumber, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN approved = 1 THEN version ELSE NULL END) as max_approved,
           MAX(version) as max_overall
    FROM table
    GROUP BY fileNumber
)
```